# IDA script: How to properly undefine a byte and then redefine code

Tags: ida, idapython, static-analysis

I'm trying to correct the following instructions in IDA using a script:

```
jnb     short near ptr loc_1C61B1+3
```

It order to do this I'm running a snippet like this in a script:

```
ida_bytes.del_value(loc_1C61B1)
idc.create_insn(loc_1C61B1+3)
```

I've tried many variations on this including trying to auto wait for the analyzer using `ida_auto.*_wait()` functions, `ida_auto.*_plan` functions, deleting multiples bytes (`ida_bytes.del_items`), etc. but no matter what I do I cannot get the same analyzer outcome as if I ran the 2 functions above manually in the command bar. My guess is there's some race conditions happening with the analyzer.

How do I properly achieve the following in a script:

- Undefine code at location `x`.
- Give the analyzer enough time to do its things.
- Make code at location `x + y`.
- Get the same outcome as if I have done the steps manually.